# sourcetree: can you reverse "finish feature"?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

I did "finish feature" in git flow by mistake (without deleting), can it be reversed?

[image]

Comment: `git flow feature finish` without deleting actually just merges feature branch into develop. So you could reset develop branch to last "normal" commit, and then switch to feature branch, and continue working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookup the history with `git log` and copy the hashes of last commits before the merge on both branches.

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -b feature
git reset <hash of feature commit before merge> --hard
git checkout develop
git reset <hash of develop commit before merge> --hard
```